# iPhone SDK: How to determine keyboard type within a UIKeyboardDidShowNotification?

Tags: iphone

I need to know the current keyboard type. I was setting an instance variable in

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

However, testing has shown that this is not always reliable because of the asynchronous nature of notifications.

What I am wondering is if anyone can tell me how to determine the current keyboard type within 
a notification?

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *) {
    // Need way to determine keyboard type here
  }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking about the language of the keyboard that can be done only in iOS4.2 and above by using [UITextInputMode class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputMode_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method: `+[UITextInputMode currentInputMode];`

If you want the size (because depending on the language the size can change) that is easy, get the size from object for key UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification{
NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
NSValue* aValue = [info UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
CGSize keyboardSize = [aValue CGRectValue].size;
//I just got the size! ... do something with it
}
```

Comment: I need to know if UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad is true or not. Do you know if that information is available in notification.userInfo? I couldn't tell from the docs and I got a warning on the compile.

Comment: Have you tried what is the result +[UITextInputMode currentInputMode]; when NumberPad keyboard is showing?

Comment: Or try this notification: UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification